# Вместо Иконок fonrawesome белые квадраты

Tags: html, fontawesome

Вместо Иконок  fonrawesome белые квадраты. А на месте youtube даже квадрата нет.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-git" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделай так, у тебя неверный путь `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

Если иконки в формате шрифта, то иногда проблема с белыми квадратиками происходят из-за не подходящего свойства CSS font-weight.